# Read a string of two (distinct) numbers (floats). Output bigger number. Do not use “if”

Tags: java, string, exception

This question need to be done by using Exception Handling(`try-catch`).

I tried dividing the string into 4 different integer numbers. Two for Integer part, and other two for decimal part.

But I'm still stuck how can i generate an error with it.

For 2 Integer numbers my answer is,

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
class s7
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
int a,b,c;
String str;
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
str=sc.nextLine();
StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(str," ");
a=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
b=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
c=a/b;
 try
  {
  int d=20/c;
  System.out.println("Bigger: "+a);
  }
 catch(Exception e)
  {
  System.out.println("Bigger: "+b);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some code you've already tried?

Comment: Can numbers be also negative?

Comment: numbers wont be negative..and i have not tried coding. I was working out on the algo first.

Comment: `Math.max` uses an if statement.

Comment: Why not parse both strings as the respective floats.  Then loop around and keep incrementing both floats.  When one overflows it should throw an exception and allow you to know which one is the culprit.

Comment: The requirement is Exception Handling.

Comment: @badjr: that's a mooit point because every method you will use probably has an `if` down the line. It's about what you write yourself, that matters.

Comment: @symb0l121cc00130: parse the values as floats. This might throw an exception so that's where you use exception handling. Then use `Math.max`.

Comment: But if I'm incrementing float values, how much should i increment(.1,.01,.001,.0001,.00001) ?

Comment: @Jeroen how parsing will give an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that numbers can't be negative you can try dividing one by another like `x/y`.

- if `x<y` you will get number lesser than 1 like `0.xxxxxx`
- if `x>=y` you will get number greater or equal to 1 like `1.xxxx` or `2.xxxx` and so on.

Now to get rid of fractional part all we need to do is cast such number to `int` (I assume numbers are not that big). This way for x=y` you will get bigger value.

So now problem is to test if `(int)x/y` is `0` or not.

To test it you can try use arrays and `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Just create array which can contain one element `new SomeType[1]` and try to access this element using result something like `array[(int)x/y]`. If you will be able to do it then print `y` (because result was 0 so it is case where `x<y`), if you will catch IOB exception print `x`.

Comment: how will i differentiate between numbers like 12.3 and 12.7?

Comment: Divide 12.3/12.7. This result will be `0.9685...`. If you cast it to `int` it will become `0` so you will be able to safety use this value as index in array, so from try print y (12.7). If you would divide bigger number by lesser one you would bet result bigger or equal to 1 so accessing array at such position would throw exception so in `catch` print value of `x`.

Comment: Try to implement it, if you will get any problems show me your code and describe what seems to be wrong with it (you can use pastebin.com and share link to your code in comment).

Comment: yes you are right. Now I need to understand casting this value.